# How to add gzip compression to Hypercorn server serving a Quart app

Tags: gzip, quart, asgi

I have a quart app running on a hypercorn (0.6) server. (EC-2 amazon Ubuntu 18)

The page loads too slow and one of the recommendations is to add gzip compression.

Does anyone have experience with this?

kind regards,
alex

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use a reverse proxy server to do this job upfront. But you can also use Quart so serve its static files compressed. See this [link](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/async_await_book/backend/compressed_static/)